# c# draw a straight line

Tags: c#, winforms, line, draw

How do i get a REAL straight line with c#? the code below draws a line, great, but this line is not perfect, it's not pixel by pixel straight, is there better code out there that produces a better, accurate straight line?

```
namespace Dimension3D
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics gObject = canvas.CreateGraphics();

        Brush red = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        Pen redPen = new Pen(red, 8);

        gObject.DrawLine(redPen, 10, 10, 35, 500);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is an angled straight line?

Comment: just edited, what i meant is 'better, accurate, straight line'

Comment: Why would it be straight when the x coordinates are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see as a straight line is actually a trick.  It is "smoothed" out so the jagged parts are surrounded by shaded pixels (See Below).  This explains how to do it better than I can.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode.aspx

The images below are the same.  The top is just zoomed in.

[image: Zoomed In]

[image: Zoomed Out]

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn off AntiAlias for drawing pixel perfect lines.

```
gObject.SmothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
```

Don't forget to put it back to `Default` after so you don't change image rendering or other stuff that needs anitialias to look nice

Comment: Before you draw lines, it basicly changes the rendering mode to "no smoothing"

Comment: Well if he needs antialias, he should put it on default or something else ;)